Custom Shopware Module Not Showing in Admin Menu
Issue:
I am developing a plugin for Shopware, and it should add a custom module under the Catalogues section in the admin menu. However, the module is not appearing in the admin panel.
Here is the relevant part of my js code:
import deDE from './snippet/de-DE';
import enGB from './snippet/en-GB';
Shopware.Component.register('webeface-test', () => import('../page/webeface-test'));

Shopware.Module.register('webeface-product-wishes', {
    type: 'plugin',
    name: 'webefaceProductWishes',
    title: 'webeface.administration.menuItem',
    description: 'webeface.administration.description',
    color: '#ff3d58',
    icon: 'default-shopping-paper-bag-product',

    snippets: {
        'de-DE': deDE,
        'en-GB': enGB
    },

    routes: {
        test: {
            component: 'webeface-test',
            path: 'test'
        }
    },

    navigation: [{
        label: 'webeface.administration.navItem',
        color: '#ff3d58',
        path: 'webeface.product.wishes.test',
        icon: 'default-shopping-paper-bag-product',
        parent: 'sw-catalogue',
        position: 100
    }]
});

What I've checked:
Routes: The routes are correctly set and reachable. I've confirmed that there are no typos in the routes or paths, and the component webeface-test is correctly registered.
Snippets: The snippet files de-DE and en-GB are configured properly, and the labels webeface.administration.menuItem and webeface.administration.navItem are defined in the snippet files.
Parent Path: I'm using sw-catalogue as the parent path to add the module under the Catalogues section in the admin menu. I'm confident this is correct, but it still isn't showing.
Cache Clearing: I've run ./bin/console cache:clear and ./bin/console cache:warmup multiple times. I’ve also cleared the browser cache and tested in incognito mode.
Permissions: The admin user I'm testing with has full permissions, so this shouldn't be a permission issue.
